# How to pass a value into javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am working on a pie chart for the admin dashboard to display some data about the users. I am getting the response from PHP file correctly and store it in `result_from_PHP` variable as you can see the code below. My problem is, I don't know how to  pass this variable `result_from_PHP` to the `series` part in the code `y: result_from_PHP`. Can anyone help please ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("PHP_trader_behav.php", function(data){
  $.each(data.result,function(){
    var result_from_PHP = this['visitors_count'];
    alert(result_from_PHP);

    $(function () {
      alert(result_from_PHP);

      $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
         plotBackgroundColor: null,
         plotBorderWidth: null,
         plotShadow: false,
         type: 'pie'
       },
       title: {
         text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
       },
       tooltip: {
         pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
       },
       plotOptions: {
         pie: {
           allowPointSelect: true,
           cursor: 'pointer',
           dataLabels: {
             enabled: true,
             format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
             style: {
               color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
             }
           }
         }
       },
       series: [{
         name: 'Brands',
         colorByPoint: true,
         data: [{
             name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
             y: result_from_PHP
           }, {
             name: 'Chrome',
             y: 5000,
             sliced: true,
             selected: true
           }, {
             name: 'Firefox',
             y: 1000
           }, {
             name: 'Safari',
             y:1000
           }, {
             name: 'Opera',
             y: 4000
           }, {
             name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
             y:3000
           }]
       }]
      });
    });
  });
});     
</script>
```

Comment: use `(Yourdata).push()` of js

Comment: Can you please give me an example ? @aldrin27

Comment: Read: https://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/4611333.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS ONE

`y: <?PHP echo result_from_PHP ?>`

you have do whatever your wish with in the php tag

Comment: This is what I wanted, Thank you very much @jothi

Answer (score 0):

Build series array[in the form of json] using  $.each , then use that variable into $('#container').highcharts({series:some-variable})

Answer (score 0):

you can study the below link:

[JavaScript Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)